# Lectura de celdas

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de hacer peticiones mediante celdas de excel y no consigo coger el contenido de la celda(*1), sin embargo si lo saca bien por consola(*2). (La celda A1 = /)

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
import openpyxl


wb = Workbook()
doc = openpyxl.load_workbook('XXXXXX.xlsx') 
sheet = doc.active
a1 = sheet['A1']
print(a1.value) (*2)
ws = wb.active
URL = (input("Introduzca la URL."))
DOMINIO= (input( "Introduzca el dominio."))
GET= str(sheet['A1'])
print ("Petición= " + URL  + DOMINIO + GET)`
```

---

```
Petición XXXXX.com<Cell 'Hoja1'.A1> (*1)
```

Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar el mismo formato que en tu (*2)(sin usar str()). Te dejo el código:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
import openpyxl


wb = Workbook()
doc = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx') 
sheet = doc.active
a1 = sheet['A1']
print(a1.value)
ws = wb.active
URL = (input("Introduzca la URL."))
DOMINIO= (input( "Introduzca el dominio."))
GET= sheet['A1'].value
print ("Petición= " + URL  + DOMINIO + GET)
```

Comment: Funciona correctamente, gracias ivanc.